# Xcode 6.1.1 UIKit framework

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, uikit

I was working on a project on Xcode 6.1.1 and I could build it successfully, but I accidentally removed my UIKit framework file. I still had Xcode 5 on my computer and I copied the framework file from my Xcode 5 to my Xcode 6.1.1 framework directory. After that I can't build my project and it gives me the error on DisplayManager.mm file "property nativeScale not found" . My project is generated by Unity and the file is a unity generated file. But my only guess right now on the error is on UIKit framework which I have from Xcode 5. 
I'll appreciate if someone has Xcode 6.1.1 and can give me the UIKit framework file so I can test it again.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You can just download your desired Xcode version anytime from here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

And the direct link to Xcode 6.1.1:

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1.1/xcode_6.1.1.dmg

Comment: Yes thanks, I did that but I was hoping if someone can just pass me the file and I wouldn't have to download the whole 3GB of xcode